# Angular Namespace orderBy is not bound when used multiple times on page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I have about four main divs on one page that are able to be sorted (at least they were via jQuery) and I have converted them to NG sort by piping in the orderBy condition and and binding that to an ng-click. It works fine for the first one but when I try the second group it is barking at me that the namespace for orderBy is not bound so I am assuming that changing up the ground that it is sorting by is not enough.

For now I have some date being populated in an ng-repeat:

```
<li ng-repeat="condition in signConditions" | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
```

Which is sorted when the user clicks the link here:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="orderByField='title'; reverseSort = !reverseSort" class="titleLabel">Documents <span ng-show="orderByField == 'title'"><span ng-show="!reverseSort">^</span><span ng-show="reverseSort">v</span></span></a>
```

And in my controller I have a simple scope binding here:

```
$scope.orderByField = 'conditionId';
    $scope.reverseSort = false;
```

So this works until I try to do it again which I need to do at least four times for four individual groups on the page.

So each new li ng-repeat would be:
condition in blahConditions
condition in blipConditions'
etc...

So my question is how to I bind each orderBy to it's particular group?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
signConditions" | orderBy:
```

should be

```
signConditions | orderBy:
```

Otherwise you would be starting a new attribute with the namespace `orderBy`.

Comment: Thank you. I caught that one... Any idea how to bind it to only that particular scope so that it only performs an orderBy on the group I want?

Comment: @isaacweathers I'm not exactly sure what you mean. If the you use `orderByField` for all groups then the easiest solution would be to use different ones.

Comment: It's because of the way that I am getting the data. The only real variation is the way they are populated in the ng-repeats so the "condition in" is repeated several times and the only variation is the name of the condition. So condition in provideCondition, condition in signCondition etc... It seems to be working ok since I removed the extra comment but I'll have to look at a way to make it a bit more robust.